# How can i publish unitTest and androidTest source sets to maven repository?

Tags: java, android, maven, kotlin, gradle

How can i publish unitTest and androidTest source sets to maven repository?

I want to put the shared classes, utilities, composeTestRule extensions and … that I wrote for testing in the test source set of an android library and publish it.

And finally, I will use the rest of the modules of my other projects as follows:

```
testImplementation "groupId:artifactId:version"
androidTestImplementation "groupId:artifactId:version"
```

The Gradle codes I have written for publication:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    namespace 'cip.android.framework.compose_testing'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    publishing {
        singleVariant("release") {
            withSourcesJar()
            withJavadocJar()
        }
        singleVariant("debug") {
            withSourcesJar()
            withJavadocJar()
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

}


afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            // Creates a Maven publication called "release".
            release(MavenPublication) {
                // Applies the component for the release build variant.
                from components.release

                // You can then customize attributes of the publication as shown below.
                groupId = 'com.example.MyLibrary'
                artifactId = 'final'
                version = '1.0'
            }
            // Creates a Maven publication called “debug”.
            debug(MavenPublication) {
                // Applies the component for the debug build variant.
                from components.debug

                groupId = 'com.example.MyLibrary'
                artifactId = 'final-debug'
                version = '1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?